# How to read excel file in python using data provider

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way in python to read excel file like we have data provider in the testng
i am having a test method (using python unit test framework) and from this test i am calling another method which is actually reading the excel sheet , I just want something like data provider so that with every data it should be treated as a new test case

Comment: Usually, you export into a CSV file from Excel, and you read the CSV file in Python.

Comment: @kamion can you share any document or code that will be much helpful

Comment: Hi yes ofcourse you can do that using ```xlrd``` module. We have some solutions with pandas but yes we have a special designed module for working with excel files and that also has a lot features to do with an excel sheet. Here link of the tutorial where you can learn it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/

Comment: @JenilDave Great can you also tell me how can i use this utility as a data provider

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I mean you should specify things like what you have done and what you want to achieve and whats the problem in your given solution.

Comment: @JenilDave so basically i am having a test method (using python unit test framework) and from this test i am calling another method which is actually reading the excel sheet , I just want something like data provider so that with every data it should be treated as a new test case, Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to read the excel files or csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_data = pd.read_excel('test_file.xlsx')
csv_data = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv')
```

And the result is DataFrame structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas to read excel files in Python. From your question I assume you don't know about pandas.

If you have added python to path during installation of IDE. Use pip for installation in the terminal

```
py -m pip install pandas
```

The python code is

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')
print(df.head()) # This will print the first 5 rows.
```

if you want to use jupyter notebook in the terminal

```
py -m pip install notebook
```

This will work best. But you need to have pandas installed through pip. **For adavanced functions or atleast update question to what you want.***What is it that `dataprovider` does, so as to repeat it in python* **Specify the fuction**

Go through pandas documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/